# postgres: how to create role with insert and update access

Tags: sql, postgresql, admin

I have a user `db_owner` who is owner to my database called 'Sales'.

Now i have to create two groups(`sales_ro` and `sales_riu`) and then i will add users to this groups.

`sales_ro` group should inherit(from `db_owner`) read access on tables and execute on functions  in Sales db

`sales_riu` group should inherit(from `db_owner`) insert and update access on tables and execute on functions  in Sales db.

can we create such two groups in Postgres ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to create groups to achieve this. You can just create Roles and assign them to the users you want. For example:

```
CREATE ROLE sales_ro;
CREATE ROLE sales_riu;
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO sales_ro;
GRANT EXECUTE ON ALL FUNCTIONS IN SCHEMA public TO sales_ro;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public GRANT SELECT ON TABLES TO sales_ro;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTIONS TO sales_ro;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public GRANT SELECT,INSERT,UPDATE ON TABLES TO sales_riu;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTIONS TO sales_riu;
```

After that just grant role to expected users:

```
GRANT sales_ro TO your_user_1;
GRANT sales_riu TO your_user_2;
```

Please refer [link 1](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html) and [link 2](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createrole.html) to know more about `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES` and `CREATE ROLE` respectively.

Quoting below points from above links:

> CREATE ROLE adds a new role to a PostgreSQL database cluster. A role
> is an entity that can own database objects and have database
> privileges; a role can be considered a “user”, a “group”, or both
> depending on how it is used.
>
> A role having the LOGIN attribute can be thought of as a user. Roles
> without this attribute are useful for managing database privileges

Comment: why are you using 
GRANT SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO sales_ro;
GRANT EXECUTE ON ALL FUNCTIONS IN SCHEMA public TO sales_ro;
grant only for sales_ro role. why didn't grant for sales_riu

Comment: Hi @Hari, yeah you could have the GRANT statements for sales_riu as well. I didn't write those because I assumed you want to GRANT permissions on the new tables you will be creating and not to the existing ones. If you want the user to have INSERT and UPDATE privileges for existing tables also then you can include the GRANT statements for sales_riu similar to I mentioned for sales_ro. Hope I got your question right. Please let me know if I missed something.